# Contextual substitution of one word by another with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, substitution

I would like to be able to use LuaLaTeX in such a way that one word is replaced by another according to its context of use.

Here's a simple example: replace the word " and " (with a space before the "a" and after the "d") with " &  ", when I write in italics.

But it's not practical to always write "`\and`" instead of "and". It's easy to forget one "`\`" and it reduces the speed of writing.

I'm not very familiar with all the possibilities offered by LuaLaTeX (I only recently abandoned PDFLaTeX), but it seems to me that LuaLaTeX allows such a word substitution without always using an "`\and`" command.

Do you know how to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

LuaLaTeX code to automatically convert “\textvisiblespace and\textvisiblespace” to “\textvisiblespace\&\textvisiblespace” if \texttt{\textbackslash textit} is used : \bigskip

\noindent salt and pepper\\
\textit{salt and pepper}\\
should produce :\\
salt and pepper\\
\textit{salt \& pepper}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
     fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
         name    = "itand",
         type    = "chainsubstitution",
         lookups = {
             {
                 type = "ligature",
                 data = {
                     ['&'] = { "a", "n", "d" },
                 },
             },
         },
         data = {
             rules = {
                 {
                     -- the space is redundant as 0xFFFC contains it
                     before  = { { " ", 0xFFFC } },
                     after   = { { " ", 0xFFFC } },
                     current = { { "a" }, { "n" },  {"d" } },
                     lookups = { 1 },
                 },
              },
         },
     }
\end{luacode}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+itand}]
\begin{document}
abc and cde bande band and ande 
\itshape abc and cde bande band and ande 
\end{document}
```

[image]